# Applescript. Save the results of a script in a var

Tags: applescript

I am new with AppleScript. I want to store the results of a script.

I first try

```
tell application "TextEdit" to get the bounds of the window 1
```

The result in the Script Editor is: {1445, 366, 1920, 1095}

How can I store each number in a separate way to use it later in the script?

What I have tried:

```
-- set firstNumber to (1st item of the result)
-- set secondNumber to (2nd item of the result)
```

I think I can store one of the numbers but not all of them. I could declare the first line each time but it seems very inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the list to 4 different variables in one line

```
tell application "TextEdit" to set {xPosition, yPosition, width, height} to bounds of window 1
```

Comment: Fantàstic solution. I really appreciate your answer